# jQuery post() method not working (this) selector

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I want to make friend request system. When I click the "Add friend" button, this button hide and sent button show.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".add-button").click(function(){
    $.post("friend-list.php", function(data, status){
      $(this).hide();
      $(this).next().show();
    });
  });
});
```

Some screenshot

[list of friend list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpqny.png)

(this) selector does not have any effect. How can I do this?

Comment: If the `button` elements are inside a `form` element your AJAX request will be cancelled and the form will be submit as normal. If so you need to hook to the `submit` event of the form and call `preventDefault()` on the event.

Comment: ...or make the buttons just buttons: `<button type="button">` But `$(this).hide();` and such don't work because `this` has a different value within the `$.get` callback than it has outside it. See the linked question's answers for why.